# Is Jupiter really protecting us from collisions with objects?

Tags: astrophysics, collision, solar-system, asteroids, jupiter

Many documentaries I see on the Solar System or the planets or the threat of collisions with meteorites talk about how lucky we are to have Jupiter, with its immense gravity attracting asteroids to it thereby protecting us and the rest of the Solar System. (It's been compared to a giant vacuum cleaner)

But I don't understand how this works - yes it's size and gravity gravity huge, but area of the Solar System is vast by comparison and Jupiter surely can't have that much effect on objects as far away as Earth?

I get how it might change the trajectory of an object, but not to such an extent that it will capture the object. And surely, any change in direction is as likely to be changed into a collision course with (say) Earth as it is to be changed away from a collision course with Earth. We'd surely need to be extremely lucky that an object headed for Earth would just happen to pass close enough by Jupiter that Jupiter would capture it and save us.

So is there something I'm missing? Does Jupiter really protect us from collisions?

Comment: Probably better suited to [astronomy.se]

Comment: I agree with StephenG - fun question but take a look over there.   MIght be some answers already.